# Trying to give my program Manners (JAVA Beginner)

Tags: java, variables, reference, boolean

Only started learning code this week so I'm probably just getting too far ahead of myself, but any help would be amazing!

I have been working to try and give my programme two different personality traits: formal and informal.

I've tried to do it by using the boolean "MANNERS" which determines every reference thereafter (including name choices) because functions can be checked against this single boolean.

Each time myName is references, I want it to select, at random; either a formalNameRef or an informalNameRef, depending on what it's set "Manners" are to.

In pieces, this worked, but once I put it all together it seems to have stopped working ------->

public class nameChoice{

```
//A list of formal things to call me
public static String formName(){
    ArrayList<String> formNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    formNames.add("Master");
    formNames.add("Sir");
    formNames.add("Mr Smith");

    Random formalNs = new Random();
    formalNs.nextInt(3);

 return formNames.get(formalNs.nextInt(3));

}
//A list of informal things to call me
public static String nickName(){

    ArrayList<String> nickNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    nickNames.add("Ol' Fella");
    nickNames.add("Buddy");
    nickNames.add("Dude");
    nickNames.add("Mate");
    nickNames.add("John");

    Random nickNs = new Random(); 
    nickNs.nextInt(5);

    return nickNames.get(nickNs.nextInt(4));
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    //keeps saying "value of manners is not used"??could this be the problem??
    boolean manners;
    //as default, it choices a formal name
     String myName;
```

// Asks me if I want it to be formal (have "manners")

```
        System.out.println("Do you want me to be formal?");
        Scanner formal = new Scanner(System.in);
        String formalInput = formal.next();

        //If formal, turn manners ON
        if (formalInput.equals("yes")||formalInput.equals("yep")){

            manners = true;
        }
        //If informal, turn manners OFF
        else {manners = false;};

        //If manners are ON, choose random name from formName()
        if (manners = true){
            myName = formName();
        }
        //Else choose from nickName()
        else{myName = nickName();};




    System.out.println("Hello " + myName + ", how are you?");

    Scanner feeling = new Scanner(System.in);
    String feelingInput = feeling.next();

    if (feelingInput.equals("dunno")){
        System.out.println("Huh..");
    }

    else{
    System.out.println("Interesting...how much sleep have you had " + myName + "?");
    System.out.println(myName);
    System.out.println(myName);

    }


}
}
```

If it says "Dude" the first time, it always says "Dude".
If it says "Sir" the first time, it always says "Sir".
(not what I want, I'm trying to pick a different name every time from the same array)

I'm guessing I need to put some sort of loop somewhere, to make it keep picking names at random, but I have no idea where. I would LOVE to know. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make the `ArrayList<String>` Global and null.

```
if (manners == true)  myName = formName();
else {myName = nickName();};
```

is where you would add to the list. `myName` is just a `String`, you want an `ArrayList<String>`.

2) Create a randInt method like the one below.

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}
```

3) Make the following changes.

```
public static `ArrayList<String>` formName(){
    ArrayList<String> formNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    formNames.add("Master");
    formNames.add("Sir");
    formNames.add("Mr Smith");
    return formNames;
}
```

---

Create the list variable and initialize to null.

```
ArrayList<String> myName = null;
```

---

Then you would assign the list in the following manner.

```
myName = formName();
```

---

This way you will always get a randomly picked name from the list.

```
System.out.println("Hello " + myName.get(randInt(0, (myName.length - 1)) + ", how are you?");
```

Also

```
if (manners = true){
  myName = formName();
}
```

To check boolean conditions it's `==`, **NOT** `=`. What you're doing above is setting the value of manners to be true, making it always true.

**EDIT:** Example working code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nameChoice
{
    public static ArrayList<String> formName()
    {
        ArrayList<String> formNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        formNames.add("Master");
        formNames.add("Sir");
        formNames.add("Mr Smith");
        return formNames;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> nickName()
    {
        ArrayList<String> nickNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        nickNames.add("Ol' Fella");
        nickNames.add("Buddy");
        nickNames.add("Dude");
        nickNames.add("Mate");
        nickNames.add("John");
        return nickNames;
    }

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean manners;
        ArrayList<String> myName;

        System.out.println("Do you want me to be formal?");
        Scanner formal = new Scanner(System.in);
        String formalInput = formal.next();

        if (formalInput.equals("yes") || formalInput.equals("yep"))
        {
            manners = true;
        }
        else
        {
            manners = false;
        }

        if (manners == true)
        {
            myName = formName();
        }
        else
        {
            myName = nickName();
        }

        System.out.println("Hello " + myName.get((randInt(0, (myName.size() - 1)))) + ", how are you?");
    }
}
```

Comment: @DJmendy I'm not sure what you mean, i pasted above working code that you can copy/paste and try. Note that i accidentally said `length` when it should have been `size()` in this case. If this answer has been helpful and answers your question, can you please flag it as the answer? I would like to get some points so that i can help more people, being new and all i can't even comment unless i post an answer haha

Comment: Yep thanks :) I deleted my comment coz it was confusing even to me.
Yeah, it wasn't working with .length so after a quick google I switch it to .size(). I guess that's because it was an Array. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You check for a condition using `==`, not `=` .. So your manners boolean is being SET to TRUE every time you pass by `if (manners = true)`.